# Error en flutter con cambios de tipo: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Tags: flutter

he creado un modelo en flutter para conectarme a una base de datos local con sqlite. El modelo es el siguiente:

```
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.usuario,
    this.password,
    this.nivel,
  });

  int? id;
  String? usuario;
  String? password;
  int? nivel;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
    id: json['id'],
    usuario: json['usuario'],
    password: json['password'],
    nivel: json['nivel'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'usuario': usuario,
    'password': password,
    'nivel': nivel,
  };
}
```

Y lo llamo de esta forma:

```
DBProvider.db.getById('usuarios', 11).then((scan) => print(scan!.usuario));
```

Pues me da el error siguiente:

```
E/flutter (12348): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
E/flutter (12348): #0      new UserModel.fromJson (package:padel/pages/models/user_model.dart:22:19)
E/flutter (12348): #1      DBProvider.getById (package:padel/pages/providers/db_provider.dart:112:39)
E/flutter (12348): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12348):
```

Y por más que miro no veo la solución. Entiendo que el id es un entero, y el json le devuelve un string, pero como solucionarlo? Convirtiendo el json['id'] en string o algo así?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Ya me he dado cuenta del problema. Era que en la base de datos había definido la variable password como entera y no como string.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías :

- O cambiar el tipo de dato de tu clase `UserModel` de `int` a `String`.

```dart
 String? id;
```

- O hacer el casting respectivo:

```dart
 id: int.parse(json['id']),
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

La primera opción era la última posibilidad porque si en la base de datos es un entero prefiero que aquí sea del mismo tipo.

La segunda opción la probé y no me funcionó, no se por qué.

Salu2